# Problems running DirectX samples in Debug, "Failed Creating the Direct3D Device"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, windows-10, directx

I'm trying to navigate and compile the poorly documented DirectX SDK samples in Windows 10 and Visual Studio 2015.

I got the samples to build using Windows 10 SDK in Release mode, but in Debug I'm getting the error `Failed Creating the Direct3D Device`

Searching online, this error appears to be linked with a missing installation of D3D11_1SDKLayers.dll, which, by my understanding is linked to the Graph Tools of Visual Studio

I tried installing the Graph Tools using Windows 10->Start Menu->Settings->System->Apps&Features->Manage Optional Features->Add a Feature, but all I see are supplemental fonts, I don't see Graph Tools in the list

Can someone help explain what I'm actually missing in order to build the projects in Debug

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Windows 10, the Direct3D Debug Device is indeed a Windows Optional Feature. The main reason you wouldn't see "Graphics Tools" in the list of available features is because you are running the Enterprise Edition and your local IT admin hasn't approved the installation of that Feature-on-demand. See [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2012/11/30/direct3d-sdk-debug-layer-tricks/).

> The DirectX SDK itself is deprecated and has been for 6+ years. See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275.aspx) and [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2015/08/05/where-is-the-directx-sdk-2015-edition/).

I maintain some of the samples from the legacy DirectX SDK updated for newer Windows 10 SDKs / VS 2015 on [GitHub](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-sdk-samples), but the official DirectX 12 samples are on [DirectX-Graphics-Samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectX-Graphics-Samples). You can also find both DirectX 11 & DirectX 12 samples on [Xbox-Graphics-Samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/Xbox-ATG-Samples).

If you are new to DirectX and are looking for C++ tutorials, I'd recommend starting with the [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started).

Comment: I did my first project with DXTK, but it doesn't offer much understanding in terms of shader development. Its a good place to get something working, but I got stuck building custom model import functions and render functions, so I decided that DirectX samples are the most direct route. Thanks for your feedback. And thanks for maintaining the SDK!

Comment: One of the design principles for DirectX Tool Kit is to provide something for all stages of the pipeline, and then you can replace the portions you want as you go. There's plenty of opportunity for creating your own custom shaders either doing your own materials system or creating your own ``IEffect`` instances.  The main value of the tutorials is that they teach you the basics from device/swapchain to rendering without using any legacy DirectX SDK utility code. The legacy samples all use the crusty DXUT sample framework which I maintain but don't recommend. The DXTK tutorials use templates.